# Convert dynamic drop down into static during build- React

Tags: reactjs, select, build, create-react-app

I have a dropdown select element in my react website, there is an API that gives me options to populate the list, I want to convert this dynamic list into a static list during the build process. This list rarely changes thus I am thinking I can save few API calls. Is there a way I can do that?

For example:

```
<select>
  {data && data.map((item) => (<Option value={item}>{item}</Option>))}
</select>
```

After build :

```
<select>
  <Option value="option 1>option 1</Option>
  <Option value="option 2>option 2</Option>
  <Option value="option 3>option 3</Option>
</select>
```

Ps. I use CRA

Answer (score 1):

Note: This has nothing to do with CRA.

You can achieve this in three steps:

1. You need to write a bash script or node script to call (curl if bash) the API and save the response in a JSON file.
2. In your code, you need to import that JSON data and populate the Options. So whenever the JSON file is updated, the options will be updated.
3. You need to run this script before the CRA build step every time you want to deploy.